# Sum of clipped linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd like to find the sum of clipped linear functions. Specifically:

$$\begin{align}
f_0(x) &= \min(\max(a_0x+b_0), c_0), d_0) \\
f_n(x) &= \min(\max(a_nx+b_n + f_{n-1}(x)), c_n), d_n)
\end{align}$$

I'd like to find the set of $x$-es, that satisfy:

$$
y = f_n(x)
$$

$a,b,c,d,y$ are the inputs to our problem, all real.

I can peel away the topmost min/max, if $c_n \leq y \leq d_n$, then after reordering the equation, I can use branching. This solution results in ${\cal O}(4^n)$ cases in general. Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: When there are no "Patterns" in the "a , b , c & d" sequences, there may be no other way. In case there are "Patterns" eg "a" has Powers of 2, "d" is Arithmetic Progression , then in these "Special Cases", there "may" be some Better Solutions!

Comment: The first 2 equations have unbalaced `(`'s and `)`'s. Would you fix it?